# OpenSSL pkcs8 - use encryption password from file

Tags: encryption, openssl, ssl-certificate, rsa

I need to generate some keys using OpenSSL and I use this command:

`openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in rsa.txt -inform PEM -out rsa_key.p8`

And the utility asks me for a password:

```
> Enter Encryption Password:
> Veryfying - Enter Encryption Password:
```

How can I avoid setting password from a stdin and read it from a file rather?

I tried sth like this:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in rsa.txt -inform PEM -out rsa_key.p8 -passin file:password.txt
```

But it still asks me for a password like before.

Answer (score 1):

The statement converts a PKCS#1 key into a PKCS#8 key. Here are generally two passwords to specify, that of the PKCS#1 key:

```
-passin file:<path to file with password>
```

and that of the PKCS#8 key:

```
-passout file:<path to file with password>
```

s. [openssl pkcs8](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-pkcs8.html) and [openssl passphrase options](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-passphrase-options.html).

If the PKCS#1 key is not encrypted, the `-passin` option is omitted. If the PKCS#8 key is not to be encrypted the `-passout` option is to be omitted and the `-nocrypt` option is to be set.

It's also possible to use the same file for both passwords. Then the password for the PKCS#1 key is read from the 1st line and the password for the PKCS#8 key from the 2nd line.

This should be true for all versions. I tested it for v1.0.2 and v3.0.0.